# This function is clearly continuous but how would you write it formally?

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Let $f:X\rightarrow{X\times{\{t\}}}$ with $X$ a topological space and t fixed element of the interval $I$. Clearly f is continuous, but how would one show this formally?

Is it enough to say an open set $U\subset{X}$ paired with $\{t\}$ has a pre-image under $f$ of $U$ in $X$ $\implies$ f is continuous.

Comment: How can $f$ **clearly** be continuous if you don't tell us what $f$ is?

Comment: I think you meant: if $f:X \to X$ is continuous, then $g:X \to X \times \{ t \}$ defined as $g(x) = (f(x), t)$ also is continuous.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos an inclusion map

Comment: Since $X$ is not a subset of $X\times\{t\}$, that answer doesn't make sense.

Comment: Use the universal property for products $X \times Y$: $f: Z \to X \times Y$ is continuous iff $\pi_X \circ f$ and $\pi_Y \circ f$ are both continuous. And one is the identity, the other constant (so both continuous).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can apply the following reasoning. Consider $X \times \{t\}$ with the product topology. Then, a basis element is simply a set of the form $U \times \{t\}$ with $U$ open in $X$ and $f^{-1}(U\times \{t\}) = U$, which is open in $X$. Now you just have to complete it considering arbitrary unions of such sets.

Comment: That's not the correct form of a basic open subset.

Comment: Don't know if I understood your comment. I'm taking $X\times \{t\}$ as a topological space, not $X \times I$.

Answer (score 2):

So you're considering $X \times \{t\}$ as a subspace of $X \times I$ in the induced topology, and you want to show that $f: X \rightarrow X \times \{t\}, x \mapsto (x,t)$ is continuous.

Not only is $f$ continuous; it's a homeomorphism.  Since the open sets in $X \times I$ are unions of sets of the form $U \times V$ with $U$ open in $X$ and $V$ open in $I$, it follows that the open sets in $X \times \{t\}$ are sets of the form $U \times \{t\}$ with $U$ open in $X$.  So $f$ is a bijection which clearly preserves open sets.